# Multiple data centers for Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure

Is it possible for one account of Microsoft Azure to have multiple data center locations according to the database set?

I mean for the same service US have US location, Europe has Europe Location?

Comment: Depending on Azure resource, yes as stated below you can use a multiregion approach or a Datacenter approach in a single region with Availability Zones or Availability Sets. All services has some kind of redundancy for business continuity and if you want to duplicate  your service for HA you can deploy it in different Zones and think a strategy to replicate data (If it is a storage like a Database).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have your data center locations across different regions for different services. You can try creating resources in different locations according to your need.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/data-residency/